# i need to get dabase values in to my textbox using join

Tags: database, codeigniter, join, textbox

my view

```
<?php foreach ($single as $admin): ?>

                    <table class="table">
                    <tbody>                   

                        <div class="form-group margin_bot_20 " >
                        <div class="col-sm-2">Name of Company</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Name of Company"     class="form-control txtbx-height" id="compneyname" value="<?php echo $admin->user_id; ?>" name="compneyname"  data-parsley-trigger="change"  data-parsley-required-message="Builder Name is required." s>                           

                        </div>

                      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

my model

```
public function update_admin($data){
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('tbl_user');
            $this->db->where('user_id', $data);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = $query->result();
            return $result;
           }
```

my controller

```
$this->user->update_admin($user_id);
            $data['single'] = $this->user->update_admin($user_id);
            $this->load->view('edit_user', $data);
            $this->input->post('user_id');
            $this->layout->view_render("admin/user/edit_user", $data);

            $data = array(
            'companyname' => $this->input->post('compnayname'),
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            );
```

i need to get values from two different tables like from tbl_user and tbl_userinfo and show them in to text box show i can edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('tbl_user');
                $this->db->join('tbl_userinfo', 'tbl_user.user_id = tbl_userinfo.user_id');
                $this->db->where('tbl_user.user_id', $data);
                $query = $this->db->get();
                $result = $query->result();
                return $result;
```

Comment: any data is not showing in my text boxes is there any solution for that too

Comment: can you var_dump($single ) and tell what is the output

Comment: Error Number: 1052

Column 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous

SELECT * FROM (`tbl_user`) JOIN `tbl_userinfo` ON `tbl_user`.`user_id` = `tbl_userinfo`.`user_id` WHERE `user_id` = '8'

Filename: C:\wamp\www\sagar\propertyequation\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: when i use $single is shows variable not define....then i var_dump($data) then it return both the table values like all containt

Comment: can you edit the question and show complete view file or atleast where you're getting the $single variable from

Comment: var_dump($data['single'] );   i did this and it shows all the db values but i m  unable to get values in specific text boxes so if you check my controller and model.

Comment: <?php foreach ($data['single'] as $admin): ?>  i change this in view.

Comment: i have to make some changes in join.